How can i pass function/method as an argument in Go_route package in flutter
I am stuck in navigation. I want to pass the function/Method as argument. I tried to find the solution but I did not get anything. I used go_router package for navigation.
I want to pass a function from screen A and I was called that function from the button click on B Screen if the user can click that button on screen B. In that case, I want to perform some operations on screen A.
Any Suggestion is appreciatable I am open to suggestions if there is any other good way to achieve the same.

It's a bad idea to pass the method , you can use state management BLoC and use BlocProvider.of then you will be able to use the button on screen B to change the value or do something else on screen A.

Thanks @maciej for your response you are right but I am using Riverpod so is there any way to achieve this?

I think this is a bad idea and it is better to use a provider to store functions and variables, which will be accessible through the context anywhere in the application, and register this provider higher up the tree, above A and B

can you please put the dummy code so I can get more idea about that

Of course you can
In Sceen A:
var aFunction = () => print('this is a func call');
context.go('a test path', extra: aFunction);

In Sceen B:
final void Function()? aFunction = GoRouterState.of(context).extra as void Function()?;
aFunction?.call();


Thanks, @Elevo for your response. you are right but I want to share one more argument that means I want to share two or more argument how can I do that ?
